# Viewcontroller deallocating my object

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm loading a viewController (LandingViewController) that's crashing because my 'ConnectionStatus' object is being deallocated for some reason by UIKit, and I'm trying to send a message to it.

My code is as below:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) ConnectionStatus *cStatus;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ...
    self.cStatus = [[ConnectionStatus alloc] init];
}
```

When I load up zombie instruments, I get this:
[image]

Is there a reason why UIKit is deallocating the object before my view controller even loads?

UPDATE (how I load this View Controller):

```
-(void)logout {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
    LandingViewController *lvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"landingVC"];

    [self presentViewController:lvc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: loginButton? do you have this method, if it is then please share

Comment: let me update the code without login button...i'm afraid is may be misleading...

Comment: It seems that LandingViewController is dealloced so that cStatus is dealloced too.

Comment: your loginButton is deallocating your viewController i dont know why

Comment: login button code is basically calling the cStatus.isHostReachable method. I have removed that call, and updated the image above.

Comment: how are you loading this viewController?

Comment: hmm, please click on the [UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent] method and open right panel and check is there any method of your controller which getting call in stack

Answer (score 0):

The viewDidLoad release is correct; that is ARC releasing the object you created and assigned to the strong property.

The problem looks to be to be either in your ProfileViewController, or in whatever notification is being sent. The object is a zombie at the point where you are posting a notification. You may be retaining something incorrectly or using it (or an owning object) as the notification object, but we'd need to see that code to be sure.